# java - ClassNotFoundException when trying to init a class which throws Exception

Tags: java, class, exception, classnotfoundexception, initializer

The source code is following:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass mycClass = new MyClass();
    }
}

class MyClass {
    public void foo() throws Exception {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

Can someone help me understand why `MyClass` initializer is throwing a `ClassNotFoundException` but when I remove the `throw new Exception()` statement from `foo` function it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared `foo` to possibly throw any kind of `Exception`.

Any method that could throw a checked exception (and does not catch it) needs to declare this using the `throws` keyword.

Your `main` method calls `foo` and `foo` could throw an exception. The main method does not catch that so it would throw the exception to its caller.

So, the `main` method needs to have the `throws Exception` declaration as well.

The `ClassNotFoundException` occurs because the main class is not found because it's compilation failed or because it is invalid.

If you would look at the compiler output, you should see an error telling you that the `throws` declaration is missing (uncaught exception).